# Enabling Hyper-V in BIOS causes Windows to stuck

Tags: windows-8, bios, virtualization

I installed **Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Phone** and at the end it popped up that Hyper-V (virtualization tool used in Windows Phone Emulator) isn't available on my computer. I done some research and I read that in order to use Hyper-V, I need to enable virtualization in BIOS. And that's what I did, but then, my Windows 8.1 Pro got stuck while booting and just keeps spinning the circle under the Windows logo. So I went to BIOS and disabled virtualization. Then my PC booted like always. If anyone needs further details or so, just ask. If anyone had this problem (I'm sure someone here did) or is having it now, join this case so we can all solve it.